# remove spacing on both sides of webpage, wordpress

Tags: wordpress, buffer, spacing

I've been trying to figure out how to remove the side spacing (on both left and right) of a page. For instance, I'll have a photo that should span the width of the page, but for some reason wordpress automatically adds in a buffer.

Thank you.

Comment: Require Site Address or code or what theme You are using??

Comment: i'm using patti wordpress theme. http://www.jasonrichardadams.com/?portfolio=lakehouse

Comment: want only the image to extend to the ends of the whole document?
Explain Clearly what you want.

Comment: I want all of the content to span the width of the page, the side buffer seems too big. i'd like to change that.

Comment: i guess the main problem i'm having with this and other pages is the pages being responsive when resizing the browser window

Comment: WordPress doesn't add any kind of buffer to images by default. Can you link to the page in question?

Comment: see above link. i basically want to control the blank space on either side of content: images, text, whatever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css-

```
#wrapper div.centered-wrapper {
width: 95% !important; // reduce the % to increase the spacing.
}
```

This will effect only the content on the page not the menu. 
 The menu wil take style from what you have changed in style.css.

Comment: for some reason that hasn't fixed the problem yet..inputted that directly into the page css option

Comment: still can't make it work. maybe it's something specific with the theme? thanks for your help neil

Comment: `div.centered-wrapper {
width: inherit !important;
}`
add this into the page css option.

Comment: almost there neil….that worked…now, how do I increase the spacing just a bit more from the edge?

Comment: one last question…I edited my style.css file in wordpress so that my nav header's text (menu items) are aligned to the center….however, on that specific project page we were discussing above, the nav header seems to take queue from the div.centered code above. is there a way to fix this?